# Compare two arrays one by one and make new array using function developing javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I have two arrays:

```
colors1 = ['green', 
'', 
'red',
'',
'black'];

colors2 = ['purple',
yellow,
'red',
''];


console.log(result);
    [
    ['green', 'purple'],
    [null, 'yellow'],
    'black', null
    ];
```

I need to make new array `result` with conditions.

1. `result` includes array whom each element contains two elements;
2. first element = color from `colors1`, second one = color from
   `colors2`;
3. if colors are the same then they are skipped (not
   included in `result`);
4. if has no color in array then instead of
   this element we put `null`.
5. We need to use only functional
       programming with immutable objects.

I think I should:

1. compare length;
2. make biggest.reduce();

But have no idea how to do it. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you do it with a plain loop, without immutability?

Comment: [Project's link on github](https://github.com/igortsybin/JS/tree/master/src/Hexlet/Async.Project)

Comment: @Bergi nope) Only immutability. This is the whole point. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But have no idea how to do it

I don't think that's quite true, since you are able to exactly describe what should happen... Have you tried starting with a "regular" loop without worrying about `reduce` and immutability first?

If I translate your requirements and question to code, this is what I get:

```js
const colors1 = ['green', '', 'red', '', 'black'];
const colors2 = ['purple', 'yellow', 'red', '' ];

const colorPairs = (set1, set2) => {
  const biggest = set1.length >= set2.length ? set1 : set2;
  
  return biggest.reduce(
    (colors, _, i) => {
      const c1 = set1[i] || null;
      const c2 = set2[i] || null;
      
      if (c1 !== c2) colors.push([c1, c2]);
      
      return colors;
    }, []);
};

console.log(colorPairs(colors1, colors2))
```

Now, I'd be very interested which concepts that are used here you don't understand. Please let me know in the comments...

> I think I should: (1) compare length; (2) make biggest.reduce();

```
const biggest = set1.length >= set2.length ? set1 : set2;
return biggest.reduce(/* ... */, []);
```

> first element = color from colors1, second one = color from colors2

```
const c1 = set1[i];
const c2 = set2[i];
```

> if colors are the same then they are skipped (not included in result)

```
if (c1 !== c2) colors.push([c1, c2]);
```

> if has no color in array then instead of this element we put null.

```
const c1 = set1[i] || null;
const c2 = set2[i] || null;
//                  ^-- "" or undefined is replaced by null
```

> We need to use only functional programming with immutable objects.

We return a new array every time we run `colorPairs` and don't touch the input arrays. If you want the result to be actually immutable, I'd suggest looking at a library like Immutable.js and convert the result to a [`List`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List):

```
const result = List(colorPairs(colors1, colors2));
```